# How to Define ReactNode as a prop for a typescript react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

How can I write a React component that takes a React component as a prop in typescript?

I want to write code something like this:

```js
const MyComponent = () => (
  <span>Hello</span>
);

// this throws "TS2339: Property 'Comp' does not exist on type 'FC{ Comp: FC ; }>'."
const MyComponent2 = ({ Comp = MyComponent }: React.FC<{
  Comp: React.ReactNode;
}>) => (
  <span>
    <Comp />
  </span>
);
```

I do not want to use something like `any` or disabling the typescript type checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing props type with variable type. What you have actually done here:

```
= ({ Comp = MyComponent }: React.FC<{
  Comp: React.ReactNode;
}>)
```

basically you told TS that the props object is a *React.FC*, which obviously isn't.

So either move the type just right after variable declaration:

```
const MyComponent2: React.FC<{
   Comp: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ Comp = MyComponent }) => (
```

or just remove the `React.FC`:

```
const MyComponent2 = ({ Comp = MyComponent }: {
   Comp: React.ReactNode;
}) => (
```

Comment: I think that you are mistaken. If you have a look at the OP's code, then you will notice that the prop `Comp` is actually a component. Notice how that prop is being used inside `span`?

Comment: @Josep So once again - the `props` object is not a `React.FC`. Props are not React components. The props includes a field called `Comp` that is typeof React.FC.

Comment: I have to mention that I'm completely new to typescript. and this was what I needed.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I made a mistake on my code, just fixed it. yep. However, what I'm saying is that in the code that you are suggesting, the type of `Comp` shouldn't be a ReactNode

Comment: Instead of `React.FC` for the `Comp` definition. I found `React.ComponentType` to be a better option, as this one works for both functional and class components

Answer (score 2):

```
interface Props {
    comp: JSX.Element // (or React.ReactNode or React.FC, whatever your use case is)
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {}
```

I don't believe React.FC is the return type of a component. It is the type of the function itself.